# Cannot import a class from a module

Tags: python, module, pytest, importerror

Im trying to write a testcase in pytest for a subclass. Here is the Super class, then the subclass, and then the testcase.

```
class DessertItem:
 def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

from dessert_item import DessertItem
class Candy(DessertItem):
   def __init__(self, name, candy_weight, price_per_pound):
     super().__init__(name)
     self.candy_weight = candy_weight
     self.price_per_pound = price_per_pound

from candy import Candy

 def test_candy_constructor():
   candy = Candy("Chocolate Candy", 0.5, 10.99)
   assert candy.name == "Chocolate Candy"
   assert candy.candy_weight == 0.5
   assert candy.price_per_pound == 10.99


 def test_candy_attributes():
   candy = Candy("Chocolate Candy", 0.5, 10.99)
   candy.candy_weight = 0.75
   assert candy.candy_weight == 0.75

 def test_candy_methods():
   candy = Candy("Chocolate Candy", 0.5, 10.99)
```

My problem is it keeps saying "cannot import "Candy" from "candy""
or its saying "cannot import name 'Candy' from 'candy' in pytest.
All of this code is inside of the folder "DessertShop." It might also be useful to know that all three classes are in different modules, dessert_item.py, candy.py, and test_candy.py

Please help! Ive been banging my head on the wall all night trying to figure this out, thank you!

Comment: I could not replicate the error with the information you gave. All three tests passed.

Comment: It looks like the functions after the `from candy import Candy` are mis-indented. Have you tried indenting them correctly? They can't be scoped inside of an import.

Comment: How are you trying to run the tests?

Comment: I type " pytest DessertShop/test_candy.py" into the command line on visual code

Comment: If anybody ever does see this. The problem was I never saved the code then ran. Once I clicked save all in my visual code IDE, it started working.